# Adding TornadoFX object removes other elements of stage

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I was playing around with TornadoFX and wanted to add a horizontal line to my screen, to see how it works. I added it to my code as follows:

```kotlin
    private val menuView: MenuView by inject()
    private val controller: MainController by inject()

    override val root = borderpane {

        top = menuView.root

        style {
            backgroundColor += Color.WHITE
        }

        val data = controller.getData()


        center {

            for (i in 0 until data.count()) {
                val values = data[i]
                datagrid(values) {
                    if (data.count() > 0) {
                        cellWidth = (8.0 * (values.maxBy { it.root.count() }!!.root.count()))
                    }
                    cellHeight = 20.0

                    horizontalCellSpacing = 0.0

                    maxCellsInRow = controller.maxNum
                }
            }
            
            line {
                startY = 3000.0
                endY = 3000.0
                startX = 500.0
                endX = 5000.0
            }

        }
    }
```

It seems that adding the line inside the `center` component leads to it being the only thing rendered. The desired result is achieved by replacing the `borderpane` with a `stackpane`, as follows:

```kotlin
    private val menuView: MenuView by inject()
    private val controller: MainController by inject()

    override val root = stackpane {

        style {
            backgroundColor += Color.WHITE
        }

        val data = controller.getData()


        for (i in 0 until data.count()) {
            val values = data[i]
            datagrid(values) {
                if (data.count() > 0) {
                    cellWidth = (8.0 * (values.maxBy { it.root.count() }!!.root.count()))
                }
                cellHeight = 20.0

                horizontalCellSpacing = 0.0

                maxCellsInRow = controller.maxNum
            }
        }

        line {
            startY = 3000.0
            endY = 3000.0
            startX = 500.0
            endX = 5000.0
        }
    }
```

However, this removes the menu bar from the top, which I also wanted to keep. Is there a way to have both?

Comment: The `BorderPane#center` property only holds one `Node` at a time. You can place a `StackPane` in the center.

Comment: @Slaw, thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't think of that! If you want to add this as an answer then I can accept it

Comment: I'm not familiar with TornadoFX's syntax and I think an answer would benefit from the code solution in addition to an explanation of why your original code wasn't working. In other words, an answer from you might be more helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Slaw for helping me with this. The solution was actually quite simple. In the `center` part of the solution, instead of just building all the nodes there, I had to embed them within a `StackPane`. This is because `center` can only take a single node.

Therefore, the solution looks like this:

```
    private val menuView: MenuView by inject()
    private val controller: MainController by inject()

    override val root = borderpane {

        top = menuView.root

        style {
            backgroundColor += Color.WHITE
        }

        val data = controller.getData()


        center {

            stackpane {
                for (i in 0 until data.count()) {
                    val values = data[i]
                    datagrid(values) {
                        if (data.count() > 0) {
                            cellWidth = (8.0 * (values.maxBy { it.root.count() }!!.root.count()))
                        }
                        cellHeight = 20.0

                        horizontalCellSpacing = 0.0

                        maxCellsInRow = controller.maxNum
                    }
                }
            
                line {
                    startY = 3000.0
                    endY = 3000.0
                    startX = 500.0
                    endX = 5000.0
                }
            }

        }
    }
```